# Likelihood function of a Poisson process

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

Fix a window of time  $[0,T]$ and say that we get $n$ arrival times in the window from a homogeneous Poisson process. The maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) is just $n/T$ I believe. But what is the likelihood function for this Poisson process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rate is $r$ per unit of time then the parameter is $\lambda = rT$ so the likelihood function is $$(rT)^n \frac{e^{-rT}}{n!}$$

If you take the derivative of this with respect to $r$ and set this equal to $0$ to solve to find the maximum likelihood estimate of $r$, you do not get $T/n$. This is in fact obvious from dimensional analysis.  But you do get something closely related, so perhaps you are thinking about some other parameter.

Comment: Thank you. I get $r= n/T$ if I do exactly what you suggested. This seems to imply that the likelihood at the MLE is $n^n e^{-n}/n!$

Comment: @Lembik: and that makes sense: if $T=100$ and $n=200$, then estimating the rate to be about $2$ per unit of time looks sensible.  But you may prefer to describe this as an average time between arrivals of $0.5$.  You question does not say which you want

Comment: The likelihood function at the MLE is curious as it seems to be exactly $1/\sqrt{2\pi n}$ asymptotically.

Comment: Not so strange: the peak density of a Gaussian random variable is $1/\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}$ and the mean and variance of Poisson distributions are equal

Comment: I'd have said the function is $r\mapsto(rT)^n\dfrac{e^{-rT}}{n!}$, in order not to confuse it with $T\mapsto(rT)^n\dfrac{e^{-rT}}{n!}$ or $n\mapsto(rT)^n\dfrac{e^{-rT}}{n!}$, etc.